# go back from memcpy to double variable

Tags: c, char, double, ascii, memcpy

I have a problem:
I am doing a cast by using *memcpy* (in C) and storing a double variable inside a char buffer. What I want to do is convert back the char inside the buffer into my initial variable (double). If I convert each location of the buffer, I obtain the conversion of the *ASCII character*, not the true value of the variable

I post my code in order to clear better my problem:

```
int counter = 1;
double pippo = 100.0;                       
const int cPacketSizeInBytes = 40;      
char packet[cPacketSizeInBytes]; 
do
{
    .....;
    .....;
    memcpy(&packet[32], (char*)&pippo, sizeof(double));
    serverSocket.Send((char*)&packet, cPacketSizeInBytes);
    pippo += 3.0;
    if ( pippo > 180.0 ) pippo = 0.0;
    counter++;

    if(!(counter%100))
    {
        printf("Pippo value (double) is : %f\n", pippo);

        for (int i = 32; i < 40; i ++) {
            printf("%c\n", packet[i]);
            double x = (double)packet[i];
            printf("%f\n", x);
        }
    }
}
```

`x` is the double conversion of the ASCII character in `packet[i]..`
How can I merge all the character inside packet (i.e., `packet[32....39]`) to obtain back the value of `pippo`?

Comment: You used `memcpy` to encode the packet, so why not use one again to decode the packet? `double x; memcpy(&x, packet + 32, sizeof(double));`

Comment: Thanks you! I wil try!

Comment: And what if my variable is in the middle of the packet (i.e., from position 8 to position 15)...i have to use the sintax "memcpy(&x, packet + 8, sizeof(double));" ??  It is able to read from location 8 to 15 or i have to define the end position?

Comment: Did you test it? Not checking the standard, I guess it should be fine.

Comment: I tested it but it seems that it does not take into account the increment of the variable (i.e., i have always the difference between the variable after and before the memcpy calling that is equal to the increment (+3.0)).
Now pippo is in buffer from position 8 to 15 (8 bytes, double)

if(!(counter%100))
    {
        printf("Pippo value (double) is : %f\n", pippo);
 memcpy(&pippo, packet + 8, sizeof(double));
 printf("i get back pippo value as %lf\n", pippo);

Comment: Ok solved! My mistake!!

Answer (score 2):

Be wary that when you send something on a socket, the endianess is something you have to take into account, otherwise you can end up with the wrong value.

I propose you to use function like "htonl", "ntohl", because such function are designed to do that.

<s>Edit : And your memcpy suppose that your double is 4 octet, so mainly an x32 bit machine. If your code is run on x64 architecture, it will fail, I think.</s> Sorry ! It was wrong.

Comment: "And your memcpy suppose that your double is 4 octet," Why? `double` is typically 8-byte long in my understanding and the code seems fine if `sizeof(double)` is 8.

Comment: I don't see any 4 byte assumption. Also, double is 8 bytes on x86 and x64. Machine bitness doesn't affect it.

Comment: And what if my variable is in the  middle of the packet (i.e., from position 8 to position 15)...i have to use the sintax "memcpy(&x, packet + 8, sizeof(double));" ??

Comment: My bad, I confound some value and end up saying wrong thing. Thanks, I'll edit my answer.